# The HMAC of the form could not be validated, custom extension

Tags: typo3

I have an old extension I upgraded to 11.5.

Some bot or hacker frequently try unsuccesfully to fill this form:

```
<f:form action="login" enctype="multipart/form-data" additionalParams="{uriParams}">
      <label for="vraag1"><f:translate key='tx_yyyyyy_domain_model_login.username' /><span class="required">*</span></label>
      <f:form.textfield property="user" name="user" value="" additionalAttributes="{class:'validate', id:'vraag1', placeholder:'', mendatory_message:'<f:translate key=\'tx_yyyyyy_domain_model_login.blank_username\' />'}" />

      <label for="vraag2"><f:translate key='tx_yyyyyy_domain_model_login.password' /><span class="required">*</span></label>
      <f:form.password property="password" name="password" value="" additionalAttributes="{class:'validate', id:'vraag2', placeholder:'', mendatory_message:'<f:translate key=\'tx_yyyyyy_domain_model_login.blank_password\' />'}" />

      <input type="hidden" placeholder="<f:translate key='tx_yyyyyy_domain_model_login.alert' />" class="alert" />
      <f:form.submit name="login" additionalAttributes="{class:'submit'}" value="<f:translate key='tx_yyyyyy_domain_model_login.login' />" onclick="return validateLogin();" />
</f:form>
```

The post body looks like:

```
__referrer: {
@action: login, 
@controller: Login, 
@extension: Registration, 
@request: {&quot;@extension&quot;:&quot;Yyyyyy&quot;,&quot;@controller&quot;:&quot;Login&quot;,&quot;@action&quot;:&quot;login&quot;}f1b2b3cd8814b4e0a55da1f2b3ad184c47f0116a, 
arguments: YTowOnt97cfe48aef06e5629af4b66052e2c2a11b2b02f68
}, 
__trustedProperties: [Filtered], 
login: Inloggen, 
password: [Filtered], 
user: 
se.r.z.k.r.xyxyxyx.ovthe.man@gmail.com
}
```

How can I can prevent this error flooding the log, or when it happens redirect for example to the homepage?

Answer (score 0):

That's what logging is for. You want to know "interesting" things logging this kind of error is exactly right . Might want to use tool like graylog or kibana to filter and group similar log messages so if yo determine this was a bot i would ask what timeframe was the bot active. Can i prevent the bot from accessing the site? Do i need additional security measures? Honeypots / captures / rate limiting to prevent future attacks. But you can only do such things if you see the events. Therefore its important to log them

Comment: Honeypot doesn’t work, the error already takes place before the controller in MvcPropertyMappingConfigurationService.php